# Directory of all images in iOS device with flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, path

I want to find all the directories where should be images in my device, I tried two dependencies:

> Path_provider
>   and
>
> storage_path

and two works like a charm in android, but in ios does not work.

I added in my info.pls the permission for camera and photo library.

What can I use for this?

Comment: did you find anything?